# How to find if there are new files in a directory on HDFS (Hadoop) every 4 min using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, cron, sh

I have a directory on HDFS e.g: /user/customers , in this directory I am dumping data file of customer every 3 min, I want to write a shell script which will check this folder and if a new file is available then that file data will be put in HBASE, I have figured out how I will put the data in HBASE. But I am very new to shell scripting, I want to know how can I get the new file name.

My hadoop command to put the data of file in HBASE is as follows:

```
hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-0.94.12/hbase-0.94.12-mapr-1310.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.separator=, -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cust:phno,cust:name,cust:memebershiptype /user/tablename customer.csv
```

Now the Idea is to replace this `customer.csv` file name with the filename which is recently dumped in the folder and then run this command.

So If am not wrong I will need a cron job to do the scheduling part. But I need the logic on how I can get the new file name in the above mentioned command first. Then my later part to learn is crontab for scheduling it for every 4 mins.
Please guide experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script . it will give idea.basically first i am listing out the files and store them to customer_all_file.txt.in for loop pass the file name,store the file name to already processed files.difference command will find the new files and store them to need_to_processed files.its very simple go through it.

```
hadoop fs -ls hdfs://IPNamenode/user/customers/  | sed '1d;s/  */ /g' | cut -d\  -f8 |  xargs -n 1 basename > /home/givepath/customer_all_file.txt


diff /home/givpath/customer_all_files.txt /home/givepath/customer_processedfiles.txt > /home/givepath/need_to_process.txt

for line in `awk '{ print $2 }' /home/givepath/need_to_process.txt`;
do
echo "$line"

hadoop jar /opt/mapr/hbase/hbase-0.94.12/hbase-0.94.12-mapr-1310.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.separator=, -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,cust:phno,cust:name,cust:memebershiptype /user/tablename $line


echo "$line" >> /home/givepath/customer_already_processedfiles.txt

done
```

Comment: `diff /home/givpath/customer_all_files.txt /home/givepath/customer_processedfiles.txt > /home/givepath/need_to_process.txt`
adds an extra line `1d0` and also adds character at the start `<`

Comment: Leave it in diff level.just update in  for loop  awk  print $2 value.  awk '{ print $2 }' newfile1.txt

Comment: Give me error `./find_unprocessed_files.sh: command substitution: line 28: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./find_unprocessed_files.sh: command substitution: line 29: syntax error: unexpected end of file
`

Comment: Updated it.let me know if any thing

Comment: Thanks Mate that worked for me... but can you at an explanation as to what all did you did so that in future I can alter it.

Comment: there is not much complexity.please go through awk commands.linux commands.Please accept the answer if it is usefull.

Answer (score 0):

**Renaming part:**

Does all your csv files have the same name as `customer.csv`? If yes, you need to rename them while uploading each file into hdfs.

**Crontab part:**

You can run your shell script every 4 minutes by using:

```
*/4 * * * * /your/shell/script/path
```

Add this line by typing `crontab -e` in terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir, My csv files will have different name. e.g customer1.csv, customer2.csv.....customern.csv and after I run the hadoop command to load the data on HBASE i will rename it with some alphabet which will allow me to know if the data is been uploaded. Can you please help me with how to find if the new file is available in the folder ?